# Util.CreateAppDomain fails in LINQPad

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, linqpad

I have the following code in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var d = Util.CreateAppDomain("mig", null, new AppDomainSetup
    {
    });
}
```

It fails with:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'LINQPad,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21353812cd2a2db5' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any workarounds for that?

(Notes: I am running currently the latest release version 4.55.03 AnyCPU Premium.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a version issue, I just opened my LINQPad ran the command and it worked, then downloaded 4.55.03 and it gives me the same error as you're seeing

Comment: +1 Where to download the older version? I have downloaded the latest beta, but this has the same problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, it tends to update automatically, I suggest reporting the issue via the 'Help' > 'Report a bug' functionality (as I will do as well) and we'll hope they fix it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting - this is now fixed in a [new beta now available for download](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx) (v4.56.3)

The workaround, in the current release version, is to disable process isolation in Edit | Preferences | Advanced.

Comment: Beta does not fail on this, but unlike the previous version it fails with: `InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Comment: I am specifying a foreign `app.config` file. In order to run the EF6 migrations from the LINQPad.

Comment: Util.CreateAppDomain doesn't set up an environment to run custom data contexts, but then it never has. It might have worked in the past because the appdomain base folder would have been the same by default (although it could fail for other reasons). Does it make any difference if you disable process isolation in Edit | Preferences?

Comment: I could make Util.CreateAppDomain support custom data contexts, but this means basically taking over fusion so it find all the right assemblies like it does in the default domain. Part of the idea of Util.CreateAppDomain was to allow you create domains relatively free of intrusion.

Comment: Yes, it works, if I disable the process isolation. (And it was working before, the latest release, "few days" ago.)

Comment: (I point the `ConfigurationFile` of `AppDomainSetup` to an app.config where a Visual Studio project with EF model is located.)

Comment: I've made further changes: try the new v4.56.5 beta

Comment: I have tried v4.56.6 (with process isolation) and still the same error.